# Matrix optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-decomposition

I am having some difficulty understanding an argument in a book. The authors claim that the following Theorem is a direct consequence of the preceding lemma, but fail to give details. Either it is completely trivial and I am not seeing it, or there are some details missing.

> ***Lemma***:
>
> Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix over
>   $\mathbb{R}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1>\lambda_2>\ldots>\lambda_n$
>   and associated eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,\ldots v_n$. Then we have $$
>  \max\{x^TAx: ||x||=1, \langle x,v_j\rangle=0 \,\,\text{for}\,\, 1\leq
> j\leq i-1\}=\lambda_i, $$
>
> where the maximum is attained precisely at the points $v_i$ and $-v_i$.
>
> ***Theorem***:
>   Let $p\leq n$. Consider the following optimization problem \begin{align} \max\sum_{k=1}^p &\langle Au_k,u_k\rangle\\
>  s.t:\,\,(u_1,\ldots u_p)&\,\,\,\text{is an orthonormal system}
>  \end{align}
>
> The claim is that the optimal value is $\sum_{k=1}^p \lambda_k$ with
>   optimal solution $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_p)$, and that the solution is unique up to sign and permutation.

It seems to me that the optimization is carried out by successively maximizing each summand. I fail to understand why this is legitimate. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: If the lemma is proved by the unitary diagonalization argument then the same argument makes the theorem trivial.

Comment: Could you expand on why it is trivial?

Comment: Why $p<n$? Can you give the reference?

Comment: It is perhaps misleading. I did not say that it was trivial to conclude the theorem from the lemma's claim, but by the unitiary diagonalization the $A$ matrix can be considered diagonal (without loss of generality), which makes the theorem rather obvious. Indeed, we then have to maximize $\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j w_j$ where $0\le w_j\le 1$, $\sum w_j=p$.

Comment: How did you arrive at that form? I came as far as maximizing $\sum_{k=1}^p\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i \alpha_{k,i}^2$ with constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_{k,i}\alpha_{l,i}=\delta_{k,l}$ by writing $w_k=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_{k,i}v_i$ where $v_i$ are normed eigenvectors.

Comment: @J_P $\sum_{k=1}^p(Au_k,u_k)=\operatorname{trace} U^TAU=\operatorname{trace} AUU^T$. For a diagonal $A$ it is $\sum\lambda_jw_j$ where $w_j$ are the diagonal elements of $UU^T$.

Comment: I see, and how does orthonormality translate into the constraint $\sum w_j=p$? So, are they equivalent?

Comment: $p\leq n$ so the trace equality doesn’t necessarily hold true.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki Yes, [it does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Trace_of_a_product).

Comment: @J_P In order to see $\sum w_j=p$, apply the trace equality again: $\sum w_j = \mathrm{trace}\; UU^T = \mathrm{trace}\; U^TU = p$

Comment: The claim of uniqueness is just plain wrong. Any orthonormal system of $p$ vectors which are all in the subspace spanned by $(v_1,\ldots,v_p)$ will result in the same maximum value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^p\langle Au_k,u_k\rangle$ only depends on the subspace $S$ spanned by the $u_k$s but not on the orthonormal system $(u_1,\ldots,u_p)$ itself. In fact, if we extend the orthonormal system to an orthonormal basis $(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ of $\mathbb R^n$ and denote by $P_S$ the orthogonal projector onto $S$, then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^p\langle Au_k,u_k\rangle
=\sum_{k=1}^n\langle AP_Su_k,P_Su_k\rangle
=\operatorname{tr}(U^TP_S^TAP_SU)
=\operatorname{tr}(AP_S)
$$
and the last expression above depends only on $S$ rather than on any basis of $S$.

Therefore, as pointed out by a user in a comment, the uniqueness claim in the theorem is wrong.

That said, the theorem does follow from the lemma more or less directly. It clearly follows from the lemma if $p=1$. When $p>1$, let $S$ be a maximiser of $\operatorname{tr}(AP_S)$. If $v_1\not\in S$, $S$ must contain a $(p-1)$-dimensional subspace $S'$ that is orthogonal to $v_1$ (if $v_1\perp S$, simply pick any $(p-1)$-dimensional subspace of $S$; otherwise, let $w\ne0$ be the orthogonal projection of $v_1$ onto $S$ and take $S'$ as the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{span}(w)$ in $S$). But then by the lemma, $\operatorname{span}(v_1)+S'$ would be a better solution than $S$, which is a contradiction.

Thus $v_1$ must lie inside $S$ and $\operatorname{tr}(AP_S)=v_1^TAv_1+\operatorname{tr}(AP_{S'})$. The dimension of the problem is now reduced by one, and by the lemma, $u^TAu\le v_2^TAv_2$ for every $u\perp v_1$ and in particular for every $u\in S'$. By a similar argument to the above, we conclude that $v_2$ must lie inside the optimal $S'$. Proceed recursively, we see that the optimal $S$ is given by the span of $v_1,\ldots,v_p$.